# The column name is specified more than once inserting into entities with 1 to 1 relationship

Tags: entity-framework-core, xaf

I have two tables that join in a 1 to 1 relationship

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

public class Product 
{
    public Product()
    {
        MaterialProperties = new MoreProductInfo
        {
            Product = this
        };
    }

    [Key] 
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemId")] 
    public virtual MoreProductInfo MaterialProperties { get; set; }
}

public class MoreProductInfo : IObjectSpaceLink, IElipseLookUp
{
    [Key] 
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

The relationship is set up in FluentAPI like this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasOne<MoreProductInfo>(x => x.MaterialProperties)
    .WithOne(x => x.Product)
    .HasForeignKey<MoreProductInfo>(m => m.ItemID);
```

When I try to save a new product I get

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> HResult=0x80131904
>
> The column name 'ItemID' is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same clause. Modify the clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If this statement updates or inserts columns into a view, column aliasing can conceal the duplication in your code.
>
> Source=Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider
>
> StackTrace:
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

I am using XAF 21.2.8 on .NET 6 and Entity Framework Core 5.0.14

I tried the following;

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasOne(x => x.MaterialProperties)
    .WithOne(x => x.Product)
    .HasForeignKey<MoreProductInfo>(m => m.ItemID)
    .HasForeignKey<Product>(x => x.ItemId)
    .HasPrincipalKey<Product>(x => x.ItemId)
    .HasPrincipalKey<MoreProductInfo>(x = >x.ItemID);
```

But this gives the error

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The principal and dependent ends of the relationship cannot be inverted once foreign key or principal key properties have been specified.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.InvertibleRelationshipBuilderBase..ctor(InternalForeignKeyBuilder builder, InvertibleRelationshipBuilderBase oldBuilder, Boolean inverted, Boolean foreignKeySet, Boolean principalKeySet, Boolean requiredSet)
```

Comment: I would suggest to add an identity identifier to the MoreProductInfo class as it should have some identification inside the database except for the foreign key. I'm not completely sure if you can use a single foreign key as the identity column and as the only column in the table (athough it may in fact be possible).

Comment: Yes. The [Key] attribute causes ItemId to be the identifier. It is also the foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by adjusting the attributes to use a different column name in one of the entities as follows

```
public class MoreProductInfo : IObjectSpaceLink, IElipseLookUp
{
    [Column("ItemID")]
    [Key] public int ExtItemID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ExtItemID")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

   // etc
```

and correcting the Fluent api

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasOne(x => x.MaterialProperties).WithOne(x => x.Product)
            .HasForeignKey<MoreProductInfo>(m => m.ExtItemID).HasPrincipalKey<Product>(x => x.ItemId);
```